# website only firing standard google ads tag but not gtag

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have the following "standard" google site tag tracking conversions on my page:

```
<!-- Google Code for sale Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = AW-MYAWID;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "MY_LABEL";
if (1.0) {
  var google_conversion_value = <?php echo round($order_total['value'],2);?>;
}
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>

script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/AW-MYAWID/?value=<?php echo round($order_total['value'],2);?>&amp;label=MY_LABEL&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Directly below that I have:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {
            'send_to': 'AW-MYAWID/MYLABEL',
            'value': <?php echo round($order_total['value'],2);?>,
            'currency': 'CAD',
            'transaction_id': ''
        });
    </script>



    <!--google enhanced conversions !-->
    <script type="text/javascript">


        gtag('set', 'user_data', {
            "email":  <?php echo $customer_info['email_address'];?>,
            "phone_number": <?php echo $customer_info['telephone'];?>,
            "address": {
            "first_name": <?php echo $customer_info['firstname']; ?>,
                "last_name": <?php echo $customer_info['lastname']; ?>,
                "street":  <?php echo $customer_info['street_address'];?>,
                "city":<?php echo $customer_info['city'];?>,
                "region": <?php echo $customer_info['state'];?>,
                "postal_code": <?php echo $customer_info['postcode'];?>

        }

        });

    </script>
```

This is in my header:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-MYUAUD"></script>


<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'AW-MYAWID') ;
    gtag('config', 'UA-MYUAUD');


</script>
```

in tag assistant the CDATA tag is showing but for the global site tag it shows the tag with no metadata etc. am I missing something? Why is only the standard version seem to fire the event?